# Unable to get proper element count on drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have noticed at several attempts to get a count of dropped elements it always returns one less than the number found, but if I try the same command via Chromes console I get the propper response.

I assume the DOM is not updated when this script runs so I threw a timeout/try again mechanism but still with no avail. What am I missing?

**Expected Result** size = 10

**Actual Result** size = 9

**Code**

```
var asmCount = 0;

function storeValues(values, tryNumber){
    var size = values.length,
        tryNumber = (!isNaN(tryNumber)) ? tryNumber : 1
        ;

    console.log('full boat:' + size + ', try #'+ tryNumber + ' ' + typeof(tryNumber));
    if(tryNumber > 60){
        console.log('too many tries');
        return;
    }

    if(size < 10){
        console.log('missing entries');
        tryNumber = tryNumber + 1;
        setTimeout(storeValues($('.asm-ranking .receiver .asm-value'), tryNumber) , 500);
    } else if(size > 10){
        console.log('too many entries, something broke');
    } else {
        console.log('just right, lets do this shit.');
        //$.each(values, function(k,v){ console.log($(v).data('id'));});
    }   
}

$('.asm-ranking .receiver').droppable({
    drop: function(event,ui){
        var _self = this,
            receiverCount = $('.asm-ranking .receiver li').length
        ;
        //console.log('event',event);
        //console.log('ui', ui);
        asmCount++;
        console.log(asmCount + ' / ' +  receiverCount);
        if(receiverCount == asmCount){
            storeValues($('.asm-ranking .receiver .asm-value'), 1); // give DOM time to catch up, then store
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't really understand your code but typically storing stuff in the DOM is bad. Just because jQuery does it doesn't mean it's a good idea. You also have a couple of `setTimouts` in there, are you sure your asynchronicity is handled properly?

Answer (score 0):

for some reason when I wrapped my jQuery notation in with document ready

```
$(document).ready(function{ ... })
```

it works as expected.